# Load external JSON file for google maps styling

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently succesfully styling my google maps using the JSON as made by [this site](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/). An example of my code is shown here (though in reality there are many hundreds of lines of json styling):

```js
window.onload = function initMap() {

  var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
    [
      {
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#f5f5f5"
          }
        ]
      },
    ], {name: 'Map'});
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {lat: 51.529517, lng: 10.058284},
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['satellite', 'styled_map']
    }
  });

  // Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
  map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="load_maps_works.js"></script>
    <style>
       #map{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 100px;
        right: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Obviously this makes a big mess of my javascript, so I would like to keep all the json styling in a separate `.json` file, which the javascript loads in. Unfortunately I haven't had much luck with this. I've tried:

```js
window.onload = function initMap() {

  function loadJSON(callback) {

    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8000/style.json', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            callback(xobj.responseText);
          }
    };
    xobj.send(null);
  }

  var loaded_json

  loadJSON(function(response) {
    // This correctly prints out the JSON
    loaded_json = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(loaded_json)
  });

  // This doesn't
  console.log(loaded_json)

  var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(loaded_json, {name: 'Map'});

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {lat: 51.529517, lng: 10.058284},
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['satellite', 'styled_map']
    }
  });

  //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
  map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="load_maps_broken.js"></script>
    <style>
       #map{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 100px;
        right: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDO1KU-C6Iy7VhyIJMEPiHNtqhWLmYCl3w&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where `style.json` contains:

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ebe3cd"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But this fails to apply the styling to the map.

So how can I apply an external json file (hosted on my server) to be the styling for my google maps? Is it really as complex as all this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).  Note that you (likely) now have two asynchronous functions (you haven't posted a [mcve] so we can't see how you are initializing your map), so you have to deal with a potential race condition (map initialization, style data returned).

Comment: I've updated the question with a complete working example of the version with the json embedded in the html. Then I have a complete but broken example of the json being external.

Answer (score 2):

Move the map creation into the `loadJSON` callback function when/where the styles exist.

[live example](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20170726_style.html)

**code snippet** (note that the code snippet won't work on SO as the JSON file isn't available, the live example [(external link above)](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20170726_style.html) works):

```js
window.onload = function initMap() {

  function loadJSON(callback) {

    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'style.json', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
        callback(xobj.responseText);
      }
    };
    xobj.send(null);
  }

  var loaded_json

  loadJSON(function(response) {
    // This correctly prints out the JSON
    loaded_json = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(loaded_json)
    var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(loaded_json, {
      name: 'Map'
    });

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: {
        lat: 51.529517,
        lng: 10.058284
      },
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ['satellite', 'styled_map']
      }
    });

    //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
    map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
    // This doesn't
    console.log(loaded_json)

  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDO1KU-C6Iy7VhyIJMEPiHNtqhWLmYCl3w&libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rearrange your code. It looks like the loaded_json is empty at the time the styledMapType is initialized. Try rearranging code as below:

```
var styledMapType;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: {lat: 51.529517, lng: 10.058284},
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: ['satellite', 'styled_map']
  }
});  

loadJSON(function(response) {
  loaded_json = JSON.parse(response);
  styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(loaded_json, {name: 'Map'});

  map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
});
```

Comment: Note that this code has a race condition the map has to load before the JSON, or it doesn't work.